# Solution to Dirichlet is necessarily given by Brownian Motion (problem with stopping times)

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set and $f: \partial D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. The Dirichlet problem consists of finding a continuous function $U: \overline{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the mean value property in $D$ and being equal to $f$ on $\partial D$. In the lecture on "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus" I saw the following Proposition:

> Proposition: If a solution $U$ to the Dirichlet problem exists, then necessarily we have for all $x \in \overline{D}$ that $U(x)=E_x [f(B_T)]$.

Let me say first something about notation. The lower index $x$ means that $B=(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion started from $x$ and $T$ is the first hitting time of $D^c$ (a closed set). More precisely $T=\inf\{t \geq 0 : B_t \in D^c\}$, which is almost surely finite.

To prove the Proposition we first define some stopping times: Let $T_0 = 0$ and for each $n \geq 0$ let $r_n=d(B_{T_n},\partial D)$ and 
$$
\begin{equation}
T_{n+1}=\inf\{t > T_n : d(B_t, B_{T_n}) = r_n / 2\}
\end{equation}
$$

Now this is where I am stuck. **I do not see why the $T_n$'s are stopping times, since they are so complicatedly nested.** Can someone help me out to see why they are stopping times?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not that complicatedly nested. You just need the following result:

Let $T$ be a stopping time, $r$ be a $\mathcal F_T$-measurable positive random variable and
$$
S=\inf\{t>T\mid d(B_t,B_T)=r\}.
$$

Then $S$ is a stopping time.

Proof:

$\begin{align*}
\{S\le t\}&=\{T<t\}\cap\left(\bigcup_{u\in]T,t]}\{d(B_u,B_T)=r\}\right)\\
&=\{T<t\}\cap\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{u\in]T,t]\cap\mathbb Q}\{d(B_u,B_T)\ge r-\frac1n\}\right)\\
&=\{T<t\}\cap\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{u\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb Q}\{T<u\}\cap\{d(B_u,B_T)\ge r-\frac1n\}\right)
\end{align*}
$

$\{T<t\}\in\mathcal F_t$.

For all $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $u\in[0,t]\cap\mathbb Q$, $\{d(B_u,B_T)\ge r-\frac1n\}\in\mathcal F_{T\vee u}$, so $\{T<u\}\cap\{d(B_u,B_T)\ge r-\frac1n\}\in\mathcal F_{u}\subset\mathcal F_t$.

Comment: And the intuition is simple: to know whether $S \leq t$ it is sufficient to observe the process up to time $t$, because either $T$ will be reached by time $t$ (in which case you gain the information of what $B_T$ will be, at which point the situation is analogous to the case where $B_T$ is replaced by a deterministic point) or it won't (in which case $S$ won't happen because $S \geq T$ by definition).

Comment: @Will Not sure whether it's that simple. Note that $\bigcup_{u \in ]T,t]}$ is a "random union" (in the sense that the lower bound depends on $\omega$). If $I=I(\omega)$ is a random set such that $I(\omega) \subseteq S$ for some countable set $S$ and $(A_i)_i$ is a sequenc of measurable sets, then the union $\bigcup_{i \in I(\omega)} A_i$ does not necessarily to be measurable, I think.

Comment: @saz Indeed the "random union" did not make it clear. I added a line so that we can see it does not raise an issue in this situation.

Comment: @Will But the $r_n$ in my post ist not a real nonzero number, it is again a random number that depends on $\omega$. Did you consider that?

Comment: @vaoy I did not consider that indeed but $r_n$ is $\mathcal F_{T_n}$-measurable so the proof works the same. I edited my answer.